# Simple Joomla 3 plugin doesn't display

Tags: plugins, joomla

I created a simple test plugin to display some text before the articles but it doesn't display anything before the article text.

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class plgContentArticlePhoto extends JPlugin
{
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
    {                
        $test = 'test plugin ';
        $article->text = $test . $article->text;                        
        return true;
    }  
}


?>
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.2" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">
    <name>Article Photo</name>
    <author>JV</author>
    <creationDate>August 2016</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail></authorEmail>
    <authorUrl></authorUrl>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>Article Photo</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="article_photo">article_photo.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <config>

    </config>
</extension>
```

Could somenone help?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show your xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your plugin is published ? 
How to published your plugin
 administrator > plugin manager > your plugin name > plublished it.

Try this..

```
            <?php
            /**
             * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2016 Article Photo. All rights reserved.
             * @license     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
             */

            // no direct access
            defined('_JEXEC') or die;

            jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

            /**
             * content - ArticlePhoto Plugin
             *
             * @package     Joomla.Plugin
             * @subpakage   ArticlePhoto.ArticlePhoto
             */
            class plgcontentArticlePhoto extends JPlugin {

                /**
                 * Constructor.
                 *
                 * @param   $subject
                 * @param   array $config
                 */
                public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
                {
                    $test = 'test plugin';
                    $article->text = $test . $article->text;                        
                    return true;

                }

            }
```

I hope its works

Comment: Hi, it did not work.  Could it be a joomla setting that doesnt let it appear?

Comment: What is the url of the you run this plugin?
Are you sure plugin is published and URL is article or blog page like :
non sef url : index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id={your article id}
OR index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog ?